# Cannot open database "StarterSite" requested by login

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I was working with WebMatrix ASP.NET Web Pages and SQL Server 2008. It was going great, and then I just installed windows 8. Then I re installed WebMatrix (sql, iis was installed with it) via Web Platform Installer. Now I am not able to use any of my Databases, I have checked in the WebMatrix Database workspace, and the database isn't loading, the error I get is

"Cannot open Database "StarterSite" requested by the login. Login failed for user 'sa'".

**What I tried:** I have Googled alot for this, tried what was told. I tried to repair the WebMatrix from control panel, I reinstalled SQL Server 2008. In the WebMatrix Site workspace, there was an error .NET Framework 2.0 not installed! I tried to install it. But still the same issue is being provided everywhere.

I have also replaced the files that I had while I was using windows 7. They are in the place where they belong. But the issue is still there.

**Why I am here:** I am here, because I have tried Google and I have also tried to post my own question on [forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net). But everytime I did not succeed, so I tried to get some help from here. I have also tried reading some question posted here too. But they are not helping me out.

**My Question:** Where will I find the connection settings for my website's databases. Is it in the web.config? Or is it somewhere in the Microsoft SQL folder?

Line in error:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("StarterSite", "UserProfile", "UserId", "Email", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Stack Trace is giving this exception:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "StarterSite" requested by the login. The login failed.
```

Login failed for user 'sa'.]

Comment: Can you login to SQL Server via SSMS? Do you see your DB there?

Comment: I don't think I have SSMS, and also I am able to see my Databases in WebMatrix. I will check in SSMS too.

Comment: I don't have it. I have searched but there is no such thing as SQL Server management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the files of SQL Server. It was not fully installed and the Login was not successfull in Windows 8 as SQL Server SP2 doesnot work in Windows 8. I was told to install SQL Server SP3 which is compatible with Windows 8.

I have tried to post the question on IIS forums, but never got time to ask whether SQL Server Sp2 is going to get some passage for Windows 8 too or not. Well I am hoping for best! :)

Answer (score -1):

Try to open the site from a newly installed browser. I think the problem is that a cookie stucked in your browser and it tries to login with your Windows account.
If it does not work, comment the error line and try it again.

Comment: Just give me one reason and tell me when we install new window, is there any previous browser saved? NO! Everything is newly installed buddy.

Comment: If you use Chrome or any modern browser, it can store your cookies in a cloud. So it could easily happen, buddy.

Comment: According to me, it don't even store the latest password and history brother, suppose you were browsing, and all of a sudden pop-in some CD for a new window, install come back! NO HISTORY! Happened to me 5+ times. So, saving cookies? If it saved Cookies we didn't have to login facebook everytime we installed it.